# .net generate constructor based on fields .net

Tags: .net, constructor, field, generator

I'm producing very code using Identities Project to represent the objects, but it is some 1000 entities, and i need to know if exists some plugin or something .net free than produces auto contructor to each instance based on class fields.

Example

```
class Thing {
  public readonly string a;
  public readonly Object b;
}

// Generated
public Thing(string a, Object b){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
```

apreciate the help thanks :)

Comment: @bzlm, not for read-only fields, they can only be set in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper could help with this. But it sounds like some sort of code generation might be a better bet.